# How to make TestField behave the same as MouseArea on click events

Tags: qt, qml, click, textfield, qt6

I'm on QT 6.6.1 under Windows 64 bits, I have found this:

```qml
MouseArea {
    onClicked: { console.log("clicked") }
    onPressAndHold: { console.log("pressAndHold") }
    onReleased: { console.log("released") }
}
```

when holding, it only shows "pressAndHold" (it skips the initial click), and on release, it shows "released", and on single click, it shows "clicked" and "released". This is correct behaviour if you ask me.

```qml
TextField {
    onPressed: { console.log("pressed") }
    onPressAndHold: { console.log("pressAndHold") }
    onReleased: { console.log("released") }
}
```

But when using a `TextField, when holding it first, it shows "press", and after a delay, it shows "pressAndHold", and **on release, it does not show anything (it should show "released")**, and on single click, it shows "pressed" and "released".

In best case scenario, I would like the `TextField` to behave the same way as `MouseArea` when clicking (so skip initial click if "pressAndHold", and "release" when releasing the mouse button).

Was this difference meant by design?

Is there a way to set the `TextField` mouse clicks events the same way as `MouseArea`?

This behaviour is in 6.6.1, win64 build, tested on Android emulator as well as MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bit surprising. You can get a 'onReleased' event after a hold event if you do not accept the pressAndHold:

```
TextField {
    onPressed: { console.log("pressed") }
    onPressAndHold: event => { 
         // do not accept this event
         event.accepted = false; 
         console.log("pressAndHold")
    }
    onReleased: { console.log("released") }
}
```

Comment: great, is somehow moves me forward, but its not entirely what I am looking for. Is it possible to adapt that that priority sequence would be PressAndHold, if i dont hold enough it gives just "pressed" and then "released", however also when i hold long enough it would give PressAndHold and when released it will also give "released"?

Comment: You will always end up in a pressed before pressAndHold because you can't predict the future. This the difference to your mouse area, where you react on a click, which in turn is a press/release cycle.

Comment: then at least to have "release" trigger if i click out of PressAndHold?

Comment: In my above example you get a release event for both, press and pressAndHold